# Resizing a container to a percentage of its content

Tags: css

Is there a way to resize a container to a *percentage of its own content*?

I'm having a tricky issue relating to scaled content. Doing a `transform: scale(...)` on something works as far as having it display as I'd like, but unfortunately, the content still has the same *effective* size of the original content. This is problematic when content needs to flow below the scaled content without vertical spacing.

For example, given this HTML:

```
<div class="scaled-preview">
  <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
<div class="stuff-below">Stuff below</div>
```

...and this CSS:

```
.content {
  transform: scale(0.4);
  width: 250%; /* Inverse of the scale */
}
```

...`.stuff-below` is spaced below it as though it was *not* scaled.

You can see this in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81xcg8j2/).

The size of the content being scaled is unknown, but the scale factor is known. Is there a way I can have `.scaled-preview` set to a height that is a percentage of its own content?

Comment: I do not see a pure CSS solution for this. `transform` is indeed a property that knows its own size, however [`the transform property does not affect the flow of the content surrounding the transformed element.`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering) I'm not sure what the outcome would be, but you can maybe look for a different approach or just use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be quite the solution you're looking for, but it may solve your problem in an unusual way.

By the time the browser is calculating transform information, the layout is sadly solidified, so I wasn't able to think of a way to have the content height reflect the transformed height. So, I tried working off of font-size instead. It transitions just as well, and you can even size elements off of it using `em` values. The only downside is, I had to specify a particular `width: xxem` value so that the varying font-size would not cause line breaks in the middle of the transition.

https://jsfiddle.net/07c7s83y/

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I have to scale unpredictable content, so I can't rely on the font sizing to be the only factor affecting the content size.

Comment: @Jacob I can certainly imagine some types of content being unpredictable, but keep in mind that width, height, margins, padding, and all kinds of other unit types can use `em` to define their size, in which case they would **all** derive from `font-size`. I guess other possibilities might come up if you're willing to use JavaScript for it. (You don't necessarily need to animate each frame using JavaScript, but perhaps dynamically determine future sizes)